# Abrir documento na rede - Delphi

Tags: delphi, redes

Como faço para abrir no `Delphi` um documento, word ou PDF, que está na rede?

Localmente eu consigo abrir, mas quando uso um caminho da rede (Ex.: `\\Servidor\c\sistema\documento.doc`) retorna uma mensagem de erro que o arquivo não foi encontrado.

Uso o seguinte comando:

```
OpenDialog1.FileName := '\\Servidor\c\sistema\documento.doc';
```

Comment: Já experimentou colar este mesmo caminho no Windows Explorer para verificar se ele está correto? Falta uma contrabarra no começo do caminho (antes do nome do servidor, utiliza duas contrabarras). Verifique também se há mesmo um compartilhamento chamado "c" e se a intenção não era usar o compartilhamento adminstrativo "c$".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu acredito que como o arquivo esteja em outro computador seja algo assim:

```
const
  RemoteName = '\\ntmemo01\C$';
  UserName = 'yourusername';
  Password = 'yourpassword';

function MapNetworkDrive: Boolean;
var
  NetRes: TNetResource;
  Res: DWord;
begin
  Result := True;
  FillChar(NetRes, SizeOf(TNetResource), 0);
  NetRes.dwType := RESOURCETYPE_DISK;
  NetRes.lpRemoteName := PChar(RemoteName);
  NetRes.lpLocalName := 'H:';   // Whatever drive letter you want
  Res := WNetAddConnection2(NetRes, PChar(Password), PChar(UserName), 0);
  Result := (Res = NO_ERROR);
end;
```

caso não esteja mapeado

```
function UnMapNetworkDrive: Boolean;
var
  Res: DWord;
begin
  Res := WNetCancelConnection2(PChar('H:'), 0, True); // same drive letter as above
  Result := (Res + NO_ERROR);
end;
```

Retirado [daqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/606324/delphi-open-a-file-from-another-computer)

Answer (score 0):

Para abrir um documento, como um arquivo Word ou PDF, em uma aplicação Delphi, você pode usar o componente "ShellExecute" da biblioteca "Windows". Esse componente permite executar um arquivo ou programa externo a partir de um aplicativo Delphi.

A sintaxe básica para usar o "ShellExecute" é a seguinte:

ShellExecute(Handle, 'open', PChar(NomeArquivo), nil, nil, SW_SHOWNORMAL);

Onde:

```
"Handle" é o handle da janela da sua aplicação Delphi
"open" é a ação que você quer realizar com o arquivo (neste caso, abrir o arquivo)
"NomeArquivo" é o caminho completo do arquivo que você quer abrir
"SW_SHOWNORMAL" é a forma como o arquivo será aberto (no modo normal)
```

Para abrir um arquivo em rede, basta incluir o caminho completo do arquivo na rede no lugar do "NomeArquivo". Por exemplo:

ShellExecute(Handle, 'open', PChar('\servidor\pasta\arquivo.pdf'), nil, nil, SW_SHOWNORMAL);

Observe que é necessário ter permissão de acesso ao arquivo na rede para abri-lo com o "ShellExecute".

Espero que isso ajude! Se você tiver mais alguma dúvida ou precisar de mais informações, sinta-se à vontade para perguntar.